# Customize Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have problem in Navigation Controller. I can't create dynamic buttons on Navigation Bar.
I have used Navigation Bar. Inside this, I have one TabBar.
And Inside TabBar, I have one more Navigation Controller.

I can create buttons on that. But I want Dynamic buttons on parent Navigation controller of TabBar.

For Button It's not working.
My Code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(btnClick:)];

//[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:searchBtn];

[app.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:searchBtn];
[searchBtn release];
```

For Hide the parent Navigation Controller, It's working.

```
app.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;
```

How can I solve this problem.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you should change this

```
   [app.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:searchBtn];
[searchBtn release];
```

into

```
[app.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:searchBtn];
[searchBtn release];
```

Comment: It throws an error.
because navigationItem is a property of navigationController which is declared in delegate.

Comment: then try this self.tabBarController.navigationItem

Comment: Its not working.
anyways Thanks.
I have done via alternative solution by hiding parent controller.